# If $X \times Y = X \times Z$ and $X \neq \emptyset$, then $Y = Z$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I got a pretty good idea for the proof but it feels like it's missing some details.

Proof:
$$X \times Y \Leftrightarrow a\in X \land b \in Y \Leftrightarrow a\in X \land b\in Z$$

Since $b\in Y \Leftrightarrow b\in Z$, then $Y = Z \blacksquare$

I feel like the jump to $b\in Y \Leftrightarrow b\in Z$ is flawed is some way, missing some details. Can anyone help me justify it more or tell me that it's good?

Comment: Your proof does not make sense as written. I have written a concise proof below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not clearly state where and how you use $X\ne \emptyset$, and you should start from $Y$ or $Z$ and not the products.

Let $y\in Y$ be arbitrary. As $X\ne\emptyset$, there exists some $x\in X$.
Then $(x,y)\in X\times Y=X\times Z$, i.e., $(x,y)=(u,v)$ for some $u\in X$, $v\in Z$. By definition of ordered pairs, this means ($x=u$ and) $y=v$. In particular, $y\in Z$. We conclude $Y\subseteq Z$.
The other direction, $Z\subseteq Y$ , follows the same way,

Comment: Thank you. The definition of ordered pairs helped me see the bridge to proving they are subsets of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y \in Y$. Since $X \neq \emptyset $ , let $x \in X$. Consider $(x,y) \in X \times Y = X \times Z$ which implies $y \in Z$. The other way is proven similarly.